# SQLite - load_extension switch questions

Tags: sqlite

I am using 32-bit SQLite 3.32.3 (downloaded pre-compiled binaries) on a laptop with 64-bit Windows 10.
I have failed to locate an answer with Google search.

1. How do I toggle the state of the load_extension switch?
   In the SQLite CLI, when I open a database and query .dbconfig, load_extension is on.
   I switch if off with `dbconfig load_extension off;` which reports

> ERROR: Not a boolean value: "off;". Assuming "no".
> load_extension off

In spite of the reported error, load_extension is turned off. However, when I restart the SQLite CLI and query .dbconfig, load_extension is on (it has reverted).

2. Is the switch session bound? Applicable to the database or is it global?
3. What is the correct way to manage this switch using the SQLite CLI on Windows?

Comment: The error comes because of the semi colon. According to the [sqlite doc](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/db_config.html) it applies to the _connection_.

Comment: Thank you; your explanation clarifies the issue perfectly.